# Disable Lint Info 768 for all struct members

Tags: c, pc-lint

I don't know if this is the right place to ask the question but I will do it anyway.

I have a problem with Lint, I am currently migrating some code from another project and there are many struct members which are currently not used in the new project. And of course because of this Lint is complaining with:

Info 768: global struct member 'foo' (line 89, file /path/header.h) not referenced

I would like to supress these messages at the moment (as they break our build), but I would not like to do it globally because parallel to migration, there is code being implemented and we want to prevent struct members not being used. So I am left with the option of using the global configuration file to suppress the messages for these members (i.e. -esym(768, foo)).

However I have this problem:

```
typedef struct {
  u16 foo;
  u16 bar;
} t_foobar;

typedef struct {
  u16 foo;
  u16 bar;
  u16 temp;
} t_tempfoobar;
```

foobar::foo and foobar::bar are currently not used so I would like to make a lint exception for the whole t_foobar struct but if I use -esym(foo) I will also make an exception for t_tempfoobar::foo which I do not want. I tried -esym(768, t_foobar*) and it didn't work. I also cannot do inline exceptions like:

```
// lint -e768
typedef struct {
  u16 foo;
  u16 bar;
} t_foobar;
//lint -restore
```

It does not work. The only way it work is if I do -e768 in the configuration file for Lint.

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this? without having to write an exception for each member? this also has the problem that members of other structs with same name are also excluded.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have solved the problem, the struct needed to be named and not anonymous for it to work with the wildcard. -esym(768, t_foobar*) this works if the struct has also the name t_foobar and not just the typedef`s name.

Comment: Nice work.  You should post your previous comment as an answer to your own question - that way its obvious to other people in the future that you figured this one out and it may help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Gimpel FAQs](http://www.gimpel.com/html/techfaq.htm#q13)

Some of the common mistakes in message suppression are:

5. You're using lint comments within your source code but they have no effect.  Make sure to include the word 'lint' with no space before it.

   ```
   //lint -e620          - OK 
   //-e620          - won't work
   //  lint -e620    - won't work
   ```

The code snippet in the question shows the "space" before line which seems like a problem here.